# Results on number of solutions to random 3-SAT?

Tags: reference-request, satisfiability, 3-sat

I'm looking for some published results, either empirical or theoretical, on the number of solutions to random 3-SAT problems.  Given $N$ variables and a clause-to-variable ratio $\alpha$, how does the number of solutions to 3-SAT scale vs. $N$ and $\alpha$?  What is the distribution of the number of solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your first question, you can start with the Nature article http://cacs.usc.edu/education/cs653/Mezard-RSAT-Science02.pdf and its complete version http://lptms.u-psud.fr/ressources/publis/2002/The%20random%20K-satisfiability%20problem%20:%20from%20an%20analytic%20solution%20to%20an%20efficient%20algorithm.pdf. I have seen relevant lecture notes, but unfortunately cannot find them at the moment.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to make it self-contained and define all notation (what do $N$ and $\alpha$ represent)?

Comment: $N$ is the number of variables, $\alpha$ is the clause density (there are $\alpha N$ clauses).

Comment: You are asking two different questions. Usually the rule is one question per post.